# GCDWebServer on tvOS

Tags: gcdwebserver

Anyone managed to use GCDWebServer on tvos? I've tried compiling in Xcode 7.1 and I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GCDWebServer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GCDWebServerDataResponse", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GCDWebServerRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is there some usage inside GCDWebServer of frameworks that tvOS doesn't have? Is it fixable? I'm happy to look into it but if someone already knows it would save me the trouble of repeating the work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep.Finally I got the solution of this problem.

BTW.I use **Cocoapods** to install **GCDWebServer** in my project and I build my tv app with my phone app together,but they are different targets.

In my case,I use **Objective-C** to write my phone app and use **Swift** to write tv app.So I should add **bridging header** to my tv target.

TARGETS > YOUR-TV-TARGET > Build Settings > Swift Compiler > Objective-C Bridging Header > Add this

```
$(SRCROOT)/YOUR-TV-PROJECT/YOUR-PROJECT-MODULE-Bridging-Header.h
```

Then I create this header file in my project and add

```
#import <GCDWebServer/GCDWebServer.h>
#import <GCDWebServer/GCDWebServerDataResponse.h>
```

How to make a bridge between Swift and Objective-C , you can follow this link :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Then I meet the problem with this

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GCDWebServer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GCDWebServerDataResponse", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GCDWebServerRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I thought it could be some problem with my building.Maybe some Libraries are missing.So I go to TARGETS > YOUR-TV-TARGET > Build Phrase > Link Binary With Libraries and add these frameworks etc. :

```
libxml2.2.tbd
libz.1.2.5.tbd
CFNetwork.framework
MobileCoreServices.framework
UIKit.framework
```

It is my TV-TARGET's **Build Phases**.We should also check out Pods > GCDWebServer > Build Settings etc.Because it is in Pods,so we have to edit **Podfile** and rebuild my project.This is the Podfile.You should separate the targets in Podfile.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

def common_pods
    pod 'Fabric' , '~> 1.6.4'
end

def tv_pods
    pod 'GCDWebServer' , '~ 3.3.2'
end

target :phoneApp do
    link_with 'YOUR-PHONE-TARGET'
    platform :ios, '8.0'
    common_pods
end

target :tvApp do
    link_with 'YOUR-TV-TARGET'
    platform :tvos, '9.0'
    tv_pods
end
```

After editing the Podfile and run :

```
pod install
```

You can call GCDWebServer in your TV-TARGET and GCDWebServer runs well in your tvOS. :-)

Hope it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

GCDWebServer builds on tvOS and the [latest pre-release version](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer) has a sample tvOS project.

If you use CocoaPods or Carthage and configure it to point to `master` instead of `3.x`, it should work.

Comment: Yep.I had configure it point to master.But it still give me the same error.

Comment: I had already add "Link Binary With Libraries" like your demo project.I create a Bridging-Header file for bridging Swift and GCDWebServer.Wait for a more particular document for tvOS.BTW,GCDWebServer is a really nice open source project.

Comment: I added GCDWebServer by Cocoapods.I guess the problem caused by Pods > GCDWebServer > TARGETS.I saw the settings are compatible with iOS building but not with tvOS.Maybe I should try to configure manually.